# Grails 2.4.5 Rest API GET Request: Can't get Response Body from CUrl and from React UI, but can get it from Postman and Browser

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy

**Grails 2.4.5 REST Controller returning List of non Domain object DTO**

What's the best way to turn a method/action into a REST Resource accessible through a GET request, without returning a domain class/entity, but with a non-domain/entity DTO class?

With SpringBoot, it will look like this:

```
@RestController
class EmployeeController { ...}

/**
**I am not sure that even in Spring/SpringBoot you can return a list of non entity class DTO.
** Can you return a random non entity 
**/
@GetMapping("/employees")
  List<EmployeeDTO> all() { 
    return repository.findAll();
  }
```

For my Grails project, I am trying to return a list of DTO object having data from different domain/entities. Since the class is not a Grails domain class, how do you do that, since it doesn't follow the Grails convention?

I have the code as below:

```
class ClassNameController extends RestfulController{

/**
** Grails usually wants you to use call the parent constructor and and put a domain class as 
** a parameter like super (DomainClass). 
** In my case, since I have a non-conventional Controller which combines different data
** sources/domains/entities, how do I implement my method/action to turn it into a Grails REST
** Resource?
** Is there an annotation like @RestController, @ResponseBody and @GetMapping in Grails or can they be used in Grails too, since Grails 2.4.5 is built on top of Spring?
**/

/**
** I used just one of the multiple domain/entity classes as a parameter to the parent constructor,
** in order to follow that convention like this below.
**/
   ClassNameController(){
       super(OneDomainClassOutOfTheManyDomainClassesInsideDTOClass)
   }


List<ClassDTO> getAllDTOs(){
     //allClassDTOs() is a private method inside same controller returning a list of all classDTOs
     List<ClassDTO> classDTOsList = allClassDTOs() 
     respond classDTOsList, status: 200
}
```

With that code, I can see the data displayed in Postman as well as inside the browser. However, I am not able to see the data when testing with CUrl, somehow looking at the log, Grails considers the request as successful and redirect to the home page. I am not sure why that's the case. I even removed any security to see if it was due to the Oauth Access token, but I can see that it's not the case, as even with @Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']), I can see in the logs of Spring Security that the user has been authenticated successfully and the authorization access has been granted successfully.

Pretty much, I am looking for a sample example of a simple Grails REST API that doesn't use the Grails convention and returns a non domain object.